# Homestead xdebug integration - missing /usr/bin/xdebug

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, homestead

I can`t find xdebug executable on my homestead 5.4 installation. How I should solve this?

I tried:

```
pecl install xdebug (Build process completed successfully)
apt-get install php-xdebug (You are using newest version)
apt-get install php-dev (no effect)
```

---

That executable is critical for debugging process in PhpStorm, without that file I can`t even run process:

> Failed loading /usr/bin/xdebug: /usr/bin/xdebug: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: But... there is no "xdebug executable" at all. Xdebug is an PHP extension ... so on Linux (and I guess Mac) you should be looking after some `xdebug.so` file (while on Windows it would be `*.dll`)...

Comment: *"Failed loading /usr/bin/xdebug ..."* -- you must be doing something wrong then. You most likely have misconfigured the PHP/xdebug.

Comment: You've most likely not enabled it - i'd suggest first running `php7.1 -i | grep xdebug` and confirming `xdebug support => enabled`; after this `sudo phpenmod xdebug` restart php-fpm and try again.

Comment: Have you looked at this tutorial 'https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+started+with+Vagrant+in+PhpStorm' sitepoint has a good tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/install-xdebug-phpstorm-vagrant/

Comment: @LazyOne http://prntscr.com/f3d7tu still getting an error, if that field (debugger extension) is null or wrong, on other vagrant build all is ok, and xdebug lies in usr/bin

Comment: @ash it enabled, but that operation was done several times, and no changes detected

Comment: @Artful_dodger yep, I`d checked plenty of manuals, including sitepoint one. That is good one, but not in my problem.

Comment: @AlexBelkin But .. it's wrong. Completely wrong. I have no idea why you think that this path should be entered there. If anything -- it will be some `*.so` file .. and it will definitely will not be `/usr/bin/xdebug` -- 100%. Have a look for example here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/06/debugging-vvv-vagrant-setup-with-phpstorm/

Answer (score 1):

```
Follow the below steps:

1. Type "php -i" in Vagrant box terminal and copy the entire output.

2. Go to "https://xdebug.org/wizard.php", and paste the above copied output in the white box and click on "Analyse my phpinfo() output" button. 

The wizard will show you the exact step by step process to install compatible xdebug in your machine for the specified php version.
```

Comment: Thanks, this wizard saved me after hours of hair pulling!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install cli-module by:

```
apt-get install php7-cli
```

or

```
apt-get install php5-cli
```